# Using scipy.optimize.minimize with a quantized integer range

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

Can I use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to only restrict its answer to for example 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10? Just those values and not float values?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please refer to this [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is unclear what are you trying to do :/

Comment: For such a limited number of possible values, would it not be easier to just loop over them and find which gives the lowest error?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is, if you can use discrete/integer/categorical design variables in scipy.optimize.minimize, the answer is no. It is mainly focused on gradient-based optimization, and it assumes continues design variables and continuous objective function. You can implement some continuous approximation, or branch-and-bound or similar methods to solve for discrete design variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to only restrict its answer to for example 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10?

`scipy.optimize.minimize` doesn't support this directly, but the [**`wrapdisc`**](https://pypi.org/project/wrapdisc/) package uses rounding to restrict the answer as per your need. It works as a thin wrapper over `scipy.optimize`. It supports a quantized integer variable. With it, you can define the example as `QrandintVar(2, 10, 2)`. There is a usage example in its readme.